# Как перевести цикл из с++ в Python

Tags: python, c++, циклы

Перевожу код из с++ в Python, встретил следующий цикл:

```cpp
for (unsigned int j = x; j; j = fail[j])
```

Не очень понимаю, как его можно интерпретировать на Python, моя попытка:

```py
for j in fail:
    if j:
```

Comment: может имеет смысл подкорректировать fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
j = x 
while j != 0:
    j = fail[j]
```